# Split string to key-value-pair in C

Tags: c

I get a string over the UART to a microcontroller and need to split it
into a key value pair. It must be robust to false commands. What I have tried so far ist the following, but this is neither robust nor does it work. Any suggestions?

Lets assume the normal format of rx_buff is "key,value".

```
void setCommand() {
    token=strtok(rx_buff,",");
    strcpy(key, token);
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(val, token);

    if(key=="pos_ref") { //ofc I cannot compare a string like that
        pos_ref=atof(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `strcmp` instead of `==`. `key=="pos_ref"` --> `strcmp(key, "pos_ref")==0`

Comment: "not robust"... as in? Use `sscanf`, it cannot be worse than this.

Comment: 'Lets assume the normal format of rx_buff is "key,value".' - is that reasonable?  I ask because developers often seem to do really odd stuff, like assuming that one read from a stream will return one, complete 'message' as posted at the peer.

Comment: What does "robust" mean? What if you send `"pos_ref,1234,"`, but only receive `"pos_ref,134,"`? How will you know this happened? What if you don't receive the final terminator? Will you have a timeout? What if two messages get "stuck" together? What if you don't receive a certain message at all? Can you detect this situation? Can you request a message again? How does the sender know that you received the messages? If the protocol is not robust, no implementation will save it. The message should at least start with a cookie, have a length and a checksum, possibly also a message counter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sscanf for this.

```
  char input[] = "test,1.01";
  float val;
  char *key = malloc(strlen(input));

  if(sscanf(input, "%[^,],%f", key, &val) == 2) {
     printf("%s %f\n", key, val);
  }
```